# ContourPlot from Vector Data

Tags: plotting

I have data in the form of x, y, vx, vy where vx and vy are components of the velocity vector at point x,y.

I want to plot a contourplot of this. How can I do that since contourplot asks for three values?

```
testBC = Import["...test.dat", "Table", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True];
testBCx = testBC[[All, 1]];
testBCy = testBC[[All, 2]];
ux = testBC[[All, 3]];
uy = testBC[[All, 4]];
u = Transpose[{ux, uy}];
testbdry = Transpose[{testBCx, testBCy}];
ListContourPlot[testbdry, u]
```

I am not sure which one is right, ContourPlot or ListContourplot. I am trying to look for something that provides "heat plotting"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your type of data there are a few types of plots showing vector flow through the contours. So the data structure understood by these plots is of the form:

```
{{{x1,y1},{vx1,vy2}}, ...}
```

Let's make it up:

```
data = Table[{{x, y}, {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}}, {x, -3, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3, 3, 0.1}];
```

Now the plots

```
ListVectorDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> 10, 
 MeshShading -> ColorData[51, "ColorList"], MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

```
ListStreamDensityPlot[data, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, ColorData[22][Round[n]]]]
```

[image]

```
ListStreamPlot[
 Table[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}],
  Mesh -> 10, MeshShading -> ColorData[11, "ColorList"], 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

[image]

There are also functions `ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot` and `ListVectorPlot`.